# (NODEJS) AES-256-GCM break pdf,gzip,png encoding after decryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, aes-gcm

I wish I had help because i don't know why my implementation of AES-GCM break file encoding.
I have an API that uses 1 function to encrypt/decrypt with AES-256-GCM. (With KEY=buffer of 32 random bytes)

Here is the function:

```
const aes256gcm = (key) => {
    const ALGO = 'aes-256-gcm';

    const encrypt = (str) => {
        try {
            const salt = crypto.randomBytes(64);
            const iv =  crypto.randomBytes(32);
            let derivedkey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(key, salt, 55000, 32, 'sha512');
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, derivedkey, iv);
            let encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(str), cipher.final()]);
            const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
            let buffer = Buffer.concat([salt, iv, encrypted]);
            encrypted = {
                tag: tag,
                buffer: buffer
            }
            return encrypted;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    const decrypt = (data, authTag) => {
        try {
            const salt = data.slice(0, 64);
            const iv = data.slice(64, 96);
            const text = data.slice(96, data.length);
            authTag = new Buffer.from(authTag, 'base64');
            let derivedkey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(key, salt, 55000, 32, 'sha512');
            let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, derivedkey, iv);
            decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
            let decrypted = decipher.update(text, 'binary') + decipher.final();
            return decrypted;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    return {
        encrypt,
        decrypt
    };
};
```

With this code i encrypt and write in file the result:

```
const aesCipher = aes.aes256gcm(aes.loadKey(path.resolve(__dirname, `key`)));
            const encrypted = aesCipher.encrypt(file.data);
            if (encrypted !== undefined) {
                fs.writeFile(`${file.name}.enc`, encrypted.buffer, function (err) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err);
                    console.log(`${file.name}.enc successfully created`);
                });
            }
```

And finaly with this i decrypt and write the content in a file:

```
const aesCipher = aes.aes256gcm(aes.loadKey(path.resolve(__dirname, `key`)));
        let filename = 'test1.gz';
        let authTag = 'puI0FfV4Btiy7iPiZFbwew==';
        let encrypted = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `test1.gz.enc`));
        const decrypted = aesCipher.decrypt(encrypted, authTag);
        if (decrypted !== undefined) {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
            file.write(new Buffer.from(decrypted, 'ascii'), function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log(`Successfully decrypted`);
                file.close();
            });
            res.send({
                status: true,
                message: 'File is decrypted',
            });
        }
```

Diff of my input/output files :
[Diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKe2l.png)

So, what am i doing wrong ? Is my encryption process good ? Why this only work well with .txt files ?

Thanks you !

Comment: The fact that it's clearly mostly right means the encryption/decryption is almost certainly fine. I'm suspicious of `Buffer.from(decrypted, 'ascii')`; arbitrary binary formats aren't ASCII (if it works on plain ASCII text, that would support my suspicion). I would hope JS would be able to read and write raw binary data, or failing that, have some encoding that you can use for "equivalent to raw bytes", like `latin-1` (in Python; it technically doesn't use all 256 bytes, but Python lets it correspond to the first 256 Unicode ordinals even when it's not technically defined for them).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @ShadowRanger ! I already tested this with the encoding "binary" that is an alias for latin-1 so i think it is not the problem. Any others ideas ? (It's working fine with long .txt files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a fairly small change to your decrypt function should fix the issue, if you just update it to:

```
const decrypt = (data, authTag) => {
    try {
        const salt = data.slice(0, 64);
        const iv = data.slice(64, 96);
        const text = data.slice(96, data.length);
        authTag = new Buffer.from(authTag, 'base64');
        let derivedkey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(key, salt, 55000, 32, 'sha512');
        let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, derivedkey, iv);
        decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
        let decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(text), decipher.final()]);
        return decrypted;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

I think the previous implementation was not concatenating the result correctly for non-text files.

Comment: This is the same if I wanted to protect the pdf with a password, and then when I opened it, it asked me the key ?

Comment: I don't believe it's the same. That's more likely the inbuilt PDF password mechanism.